# Save a file formatting the text Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently making a notepad and I've found a problem.
I want to save a file formatting the text so with different fonts, point sizes and colors in a .rtf file, but it just saves without formatting it so without any color or different fonts.

Here is the code I put to save a file:

```
void MainWindow::on_saveas_clicked()
{
    QTextEdit *edit = getTabTextEdit();
    QString fileName;
    fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save a file"), "New Document", tr("Rich Text Format(*.rtf);; All Files (*)"));
    QFile file(fileName);
    if(ui->tabWidget->currentWidget() == ui->tab_1)
    {
        if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QFile::Text))
        {
            ui->tabWidget->setTabText(ui->tabWidget->currentIndex(), file.fileName());
            QTextStream out (&file);
            QString text = ui->edit->toPlainText();
            out << text;
            file.close();
            ui->edit->setFocus();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QFile::Text))
        {
            ui->tabWidget->setTabText(ui->tabWidget->currentIndex(), file.fileName());
            QTextStream out (&file);
            QString text = edit->toPlainText();
            out << text;
            file.close();
            edit->setFocus();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to save a file formatting the text of the QTextEdit?

Comment: "it doesn't let me do that" ... what exactly does this mean? What is the error that you get?

Comment: @V.K. It doesn't give me any error, it just saves the file formatting the text, without any colors or different fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that Qt does not support RTF format, which is a proprietary format by MS, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format. So it does no make sense to save it with RTF extension. Nevermind.

Qt however does support formatting via HTML tags (at least some subset of HTML, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html). So you can save your file as HTML and load it the same way. Just use `QTextEdit::toHtml()` and `QTextEdit::setHtml()`, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#html-prop. In other words, do not use `toPlainText()` if you want formatted text. Plain text is called plain because it does not contain any formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
file.write(edit->toPLainText().toLocal8Bit());
```

Because, QTextStream writes the text with format information's.

Comment: it still doesn't work. when I try to open the file with my notepad or with word it is all the same, the same font, no colors. I don't know why

Comment: ` the same font, no colors.` - you convert the text to plainText() - what do you expect? According to your question this is also exactly what you want - plain text without any formating.